# Pandas: modify the minutes of a timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

My code looks like this:

```
timestamp1 = df_all_trades.loc[index].time
timestamp1 = pd.Timestamp(timestamp1)
print(timestamp1)
timestamp1 = timestamp1.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") + "Z"
```

When I print it it looks like this: `2019-03-16 23:40:28.783000` what I need is the same timestamp but minus 4 minutes:`2019-03-16 23:36:28.783000`, I am a bit stuck on this... any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print(datetime.today() - timedelta(minutes=4))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2019-03-29 16:41:13.548132
```

**Perhaps, in your case**:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print(datetime.strptime("2019-03-16 23:40:28.783000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") - timedelta(minutes=4))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2019-03-16 23:36:28.783000
```

Answer (score 2):

In pandas you can use DateOffset:

```
a = pd.date_range(start='2018',end='2019') 

a - pd.DateOffset(minutes = 4)
```